# Is there a more efficient way to find the middle of a singly-linked list? (Any language)

Tags: linked-list, language-agnostic

Let's set the context/limitations:

1. A linked-list consists of Node objects.
2. Nodes only have a reference to their next node.
3. A reference to the list is only a reference to the head Node object.
4. No preprocessing or indexing has been done on the linked-list other than construction (there are no other references to internal nodes or statistics collected, i.e. length).
5. The last node in the list has a null reference for its next node.

Below is some code for my proposed solution.

```
Node cursor = head;
Node middle = head;

while (cursor != null) {
    cursor = cursor.next;
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor = cursor.next;
        middle = middle.next;
    }
}
return middle;
```

Without changing the linked-list architecture (not switching to a doubly-linked list or storing a length variable), is there a more efficient way to find the middle element of singly-linked list?

---

Note: When this method finds the middle of an even number of nodes, it always finds the left middle. This is ideal as it gives you access to both, but if a more efficient method will always find the right middle, that's fine, too.

Comment: This implementation is just odd. You can have a counter that you increment each time you add to the linked list but ultimately you said you can't add a flag, which is super easy it's one variable in the node class. But anywho it's going to be Big-O(n) regardless. Because you have to traverse because of no flag/variable for nodes. The implementation with your current setup would be. list.length()/2. Then while loop that many times.

Comment: That implementation is equivalent to mine. Rather than looping once to collect the length and then loop a second time for half the length, I ensure that the second cursor moves half as much as the main cursor. Since the main cursor moves over list.length nodes, the secondary cursor moves over list.length/2.

There is nothing odd about this implementation, it simply foregoes a second loop because it's unnecessary.

Comment: @FirebladeDan We can clearly see that the problem can be solved in O(n) time, but what I'm asking about is T(n). My solution solves the problem in T(n) = 1.5n (one-and-a-half passes). Can it be solved in fewer passes?

Comment: I consider it odd because you're iterating through your list with two steps per iteration. Might as well use a while(true) <- hopefully that explains this misuse of a loop. It's still n. 12423423423n = 1n. Plus I said if you add a counter to the main program not the node you can increment that as you add the nodes to the list. Resulting in a loop just being that number. This will in turn give you 0.5n. Which is of course still n.

Comment: A while(true) would fail because a linked list can be empty (head node is null). Not only that, but if the linked list has an odd number of nodes, a lack of checking at every other node after the first could result in a null-pointer error.

To use a while true, there would need to be additional if-statements inside the forever-loop. This is not a misuse of a loop, this is its intended use. Adding a counter introduces additional arithmetic operations that were are missing from my implementation. Now, you're spending cycles incrementing a number by 1 when its unnecessary.

Comment: @FirebladeDan Suddenly, you're performing more than 1.5n variable modifications. You're suddenly doing 1.5n + 1n (to count the length) + 0.5n (to reach the middle). Your method does twice the work as mine.

Comment: @FirebladeDan And again, Big O is not the only consideration to make. If a program takes half as long as another, even if they share the same time complexity, that's a huge difference and is a meaningful optimization. Suddenly, an experiment that takes two weeks takes one, for example.

Comment: Is this a real-life problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no more efficient way, given the information you have available to you.

Think about it in terms of transitions from one node to the next. You *have* to perform `N` transitions to work out the list length. Then you *have* to perform `N/2` transitions to find the middle.

Whether you do this as a full scan followed by a half scan based on the discovered length, or whether you run the `cursor` (at twice speed) and `middle` (at normal speed) pointers in parallel is not relevant here, the total number of transitions remains the same.

The only way to make this faster would be to introduce *extra* information to the data structure which you've discounted but, for the sake of completeness, I'll include it here. Examples would be:

- making it a doubly-linked list with `head` and `tail` pointers, so you could find it in `N` transitions by "squeezing" in from both ends to the middle. That doubles the storage requirements for pointers however so may not be suitable.
- having a skip list with each node pointing to both it's "child" and its "grandchild". This would speed up the `cursor` transitions resulting in only about `N` in total (that's `N/2` for each of `cursor` and `middle`). Like the previous point, there's an extra pointer per node required for this.
- maintaining the length of the list separately so you could find the middle in `N/2` transitions.
- same as the previous point but caching the middle node for added speed under certain circumstances.

---

That last point bears some extra examination. Like many optimisations, you can trade space for time and the caching shows one way to do it.

First, maintain the length of the list *and* a pointer to the middle node. The length is initially zero and the middle pointer is initially set to `null`.

If you're ever asked for the middle node when the length is zero, just return `null`. That makes sense because the list is empty.

Otherwise, if you're asked for the middle node and the pointer is `null`, it must be because you haven't cached the value yet.

In that case, calculate it using the length (`N/2` transitions) and then *store* that pointer for later, before returning it.

As an aside, there's a special case here when adding to the *end* of the list, something that's common enough to warrant special code.

When adding to the end when the length is going from an even number to an odd number, just set `middle` to `middle->next` rather than setting it back to `null`.

This will save a recalculation and works because you (a) have the `next` pointers and (b) you can work out how the middle "index" (one-based and selecting the left of a pair as per your original question) changes given the length:

```
Length   Middle(one-based)
------   -----------------
     0      none
     1         1
     2         1
     3         2
     4         2
     5         3
     :         :
```

This caching means, provided the list doesn't change (or only changes at the end), the next time you need the middle element, it will be near instantaneous.

If you ever delete a node from the list (or insert somewhere other than the end), set the middle pointer back to null. It will then be recalculated (and re-cached) the next time it's needed.

So, for a minimal extra storage requirement, you can gain quite a bit of speed, especially in situations where the middle element is needed more often than the list is changed.